# Disable Default record type

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am not able to disable or deactivate the default record type.

'' This record type Key Accounts cannot be deactivated because the following profiles use this record type as default. "

Please suggest me

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is the last record type available on the object. There is a workaround to deleting the last record type remaining on an object, and it involves a little URL hacking.

build this URL

http://instance.salesforce.com/setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=ProfileID&tid=Object

Instance is the instance the customer is on (SSL, NA1-5, AP, EMEA). You just need to set the ProfileID to the profile ID of the Packaging License Manager (or System Administrator) and the Object to the name of the object (ie Contact, Account or the ID of the object).  This then allows you to  set the record type to whatever they want the default to be. Then they have the ability deactivate & delete the record type that they could not delete before.

example :
https://cs1.salesforce.com/setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=00e20000000taRr&tid=Account&pn=System+License+User

Check this blog too : http://clicksandcode.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-delete-recordtype-in-salesforce.html

Cheers,

Comment: They keep releasing hidden profiles then causing record types to be locked in place this way. They simply bed to let us set a new default instead of blocking the delete.